# How to execute a vacuum command without warning stops in postgres?

Tags: postgresql, performance, vacuum

Attempting to `vacuum` as postgresql database, but it stops after vacuuming about 50 records, with this command/warning:

```
 backend> vacuum FULL;
 WARNING:  database "postgres" must be vacuumed within 988308 transactions
HINT:  To avoid a database shutdown, execute a full-database VACUUM in "postgres".
```

backend>

```
// again

WARNING:  database "postgres" must be vacuumed within 988242 transactions
HINT:  To avoid a database shutdown, execute a full-database VACUUM in "postgres".
```

How can this be invoked so that it doesn't stop so often? Ty :^)

Comment: You might be able to run `VACUUM FREEZE` instead of using `full`, possibly just a regular `VACUUM` might also work. Also see: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/routine-vacuuming.html#VACUUM-FOR-WRAPAROUND another thing to do is to setup auto vacuum so it handles vacuuming on a schedule of some sort.

Comment: I'm also having this problem of the vacuum command for every 50 records, I'm running on standalone mondo by posgresql 8.1, did you manage to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`VACUUM (FULL)` is quite different from `VACUUM`, and is *not* what is needed in this situation. `VACUUM (FULL)` is *not* simply a better `VACUUM`.

You have somehow maneuvered yourself into a bad spot. If you don't succeed in running a normal `VACUUM` **on the `postgres` database** within a. million transactions, your database will suffer data loss.

You have to connect to the `postgres` database and then run

```
VACUUM
```

There will probably be obstacles that you have to remove first. This could be

- a long running transaction (gone when you start in single user mode)
- an orphaned prepared transactions
- an orphaned replication slot

See [my blog](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/reasons-why-vacuum-wont-remove-dead-rows/) for more.

Comment: I'm also having this problem of the vacuum command for every 50 records, I'm running on standalone mode posgresql 8.1, did you manage to solve this?

Comment: ERROR: database is not accepting commands to avoid wraparound data loss in database "mydb" HINT: Stop the postmaster and use a standalone backend to VACUUM in "mydb" I'm getting this error if I try to connect to the database:

Comment: @IsaqueNeves Then go ahead and do that.